# Menu in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I have this scenario:

I have a activity, lets call it`Acitivty1` with

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}
```

I open a fragment from `Activity1` lets call it `Fragment1` with:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false); 

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    if (menu != null){

        menu.clear();
    }

    if (!boolean) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);

    } else {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
    }
}
```

This fragment will be called again from activity as a new instance.

Based on the boolean in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` I'm deciding what menu should be loaded in the fragment so, during the second instance if I click on a menu item, I see the objects of first instance fragment.

I have no clue, why is this happening?

How is the workflow for displaying menu options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a case like this, you need to put the menu in activity and update the menu dynamically in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (menu != null){
    menu.clear();
}
```

That piece of code might be the root cause.

You're telling the system to clear the `menu` if it's `null`. Well, FYI, the `menu` will never be `null` in the first place; it is supplied by the system. It might have no items inside, but it'll never be `null`.

One way to check if a `menu` already contains an item (or more) is to call `hasVisibleItems()`.

From the documentations:

> public abstract boolean **hasVisibleItems()**
>
> Returns True if there is one or more item visible, else false.

Therefore, this is how you should do it:

```
if (menu.hasVisibleItems()){
    menu.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `inflate` menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu(..)` of your `Activity1` and need to make return `true` to display menu.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   //Your code here
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main1, menu);//My menu
    return true;
}
```

After that you get menu in your fragment also.

**Edits:**

If you use single menu file and `show` / `hide` `MenuItem` of your menu. it will solve your problem. 
Add all menu in single file.by default all menu items are visible false using `android:visible="false"`

See example code:

```
  @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuItem item1 = menu.getItem(0);
    MenuItem item2 = menu.getItem(1);
    MenuItem item3 = menu.getItem(2);
    MenuItem item4 = menu.getItem(3);
   if(!boolean){
     //visible items which you want to show when boolean is false
     item1.setVisible(true);
     item2.setVisible(true);
    }
   else
    {
     //visible items which you want to show when boolean is true
     item3.setVisible(true);
     item4.setVisible(true);
    }


    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menuItem1) {

        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.menuItem2) {

        return true;
    }
   ...
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: it won't help, I need two different menus, for two different instances of the same fragment

Comment: it won't work, the boolean is updated in activity, when I launched the second  instance of the fragment